# Compiling basic .c file into 64-bit .dll using visual c++

Tags: java, c, windows, visual-c++

I am using Windows 7(64-bit) attempting to use Java code to run C/C++ files using the inbuilt *jni.h* file in jdk1.8.0_92. I have begun, using the tutorial [here](http://web.mit.edu/javadev/doc/tutorial/native1.1/stepbystep/index.html). I downloaded visual C++ build tools from [here](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) I think. Using the Visual S++ 2015 x64 arm cross build command prompt, I navigated to my workspace and ran commands as requested by the tutorial. My JAVA_HOME is set to
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92`.

The commands I ran consist of

```
cl -Ic:"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\include" -Ic:"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\include\win32" -LD HelloWorldImp.c -Fehello.dll
cl -Ic:"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -Ic:"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" -LD HelloWorldImp.c -Fehello.dll
```

All of these *should* work, yet it always brings up `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'jni.h': No such file or directory`. The commands can generate a .dll despite that, yet it is only 32-bit. I have seen countless other questions similar to this one, yet none with answers that worked for me. What am I missing?

Comment: *"All of these should work, yet they don't"* is not a very good description of the problem. Please provide the error messages etc relevant information.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that part. The error given is `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'jni.h': No such file or directory`. The commands can generate a .dll despite that, yet it is only 32-bit.

Comment: Better if you *edit* the question with that info. Also, do you have the *jni.h* file in the expected location in the file system?

Comment: I have _jni.h_ in `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_92/include/`, but none in `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_92/include/win32/`. Is that the problem?